# Keeping terminal background transparent but not vim background?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I want to keep the terminal background somewhat transparent, but when I open vim

```
vim filename.txt
```

it opens it in terminal (as I want) but the background of the vim is somewhat transparent too. Can I make this background not transparent?

Comment: Hi there, I’ve noticed you’ve been crossposting on SO and [vi.se]. Please don’t.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Is there a way to have one post link on both sides? I feel like I get different (both good) answers from different sites (It's hectic for me to keep up with both sites too, so I'm hoping there is a good solution to have one post link to both).

Comment: There is not—its considered an anti-pattern on SO and friends. That said, I’m no expert on policies. Consider asking on meta (here and there; that might be appropriate—i remember advice along the lines of if the questions can be crafted for diff audiences on diff sites, it might be doable).

Answer (score 1):

The overall background color in Vim is determined by the [`:help hl-Normal`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-Normal) group. If you set a color that is (slightly) different from the default (probably black or white) color (that your terminal interprets as transparent), this should return you to an actual background color. As your terminal probably supports 256 colors, you should find a color that's almost white / black:

```
highlight Normal ctermbg=230
```

Note that this assumes that your terminal just interprets one color as transparent; if the whole color palette is transparent (to various degrees, based on the saturation), you'd have to deviate more from the default, and probably then suffer from low contrast (in addition to the still existing but diminished transparency). In that case, it would probably be better to completely disable transparence, or at least scale it down.

Comment: Thanks. I stuck with it being transparent (your line made my background color yellow)